# Reading data from serial port c#

Tags: c#, serial-port

I'm trying to read char from port. Writing to the port works perfectly, reading - not so much.

Here is my code:

```
private void Com_Port_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    char val;
    try
    {
        val = Convert.ToChar(Com_Port.ReadByte()); // get the new byte from port       
        label6.Text = Convert.ToString(val);
    }
    catch (Exception) { }
}
```

`label6` doesn't changes it's text. The code sends data perfectly.
More info: When I send data to the port, it echo the data back to me.
Cracking my head over it for the past 4 hours.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [edit] your question to explain what you expect to see, what actually happens and what you have tried to resolve those differences. We can't do much with solely "doesn't work".

Comment: _"label6 doesn't changes it's text"_ - so put a breakpoint in your empty `catch` and inspect the exception.

Comment: The DataReceived event is fired on a worker thread.  A worker thread is not allowed to update UI, BeginInvoke is required.  Do not hide exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use readexisting method try to read a string if string is null that means some problem in hardware. if not null then process your string and extract that particular char

```
private void Com_Port_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        char val;
        try
        {
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            string data = sp.ReadExisting();
            val=Your_method_to_process_string(data);
            label6.Text = Convert.ToString(val);
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
    }
```